# Is it possible to only generate JUnit report for failures

Tags: gradle, junit

Im currently working on a project that has a module containing 5000+ JUnit test cases, and I would like gradle to output only JUnit test case failures as the success output doesnt really add much.

Is there any way to configure this easily in Grails? Or do I have to go down the custom formatter route?

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it

1. Use an `afterTest { ... }` closure to capture the test failures in a list
2. Create a TestReport task and use the list to configure [reportOn(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestReport.html#reportOn(java.lang.Object...))

Note that step 2 might need to use a closure to delay the calculation